# Authentication request works on Postman but not with POST request

Tags: authentication, post, python-requests, postman, form-data

I am sending an authentication request with POST request in a python script:

```
AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/api/' + API_VERSION + '/Authentification.json/LogIn?'
PAYLOAD = {'login': USER_NAME, 'password': PASSWORD}
DATA = PAYLOAD
HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} 
if proxies != None:
        response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, headers=HEADERS, data=DATA, proxies=proxies, allow_redirects=True)
```

Above code doesn't work unless I replace:

```
AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/api/' + API_VERSION + '/Authentification.json/LogIn?'
```

With:

```
AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/api/' + API_VERSION + '/Authentification.json/LogIn' + '?login=' + USER_NAME + '&password=' + PASSWORD
```

That's normal you would say because I use a **multipart/form-data** Content-Type, but how come it works on POSTMAN? Please find capture below:

My question is how to make it work with POST request, so that I don't have to include login/password in the post URL because it is not very secure although it is performed over SSL.

[image]

Comment: I don't see it works in Postman. All there's in the picture is the request, but no information regarding a response. Could you add that as well?

Comment: Done. Replaced the capture